# Hibernate ManyToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have `ManyToMany` mapping like this:

```
@XmlTransient
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "users_clients",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id"))
    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }
```

And other side:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "clients")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

So as you can see I have `JoinColumn name = user_id` and `client_id` but hibernate mapps this columns with names userS_id and clientS_id as their tables names. Why that happening? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the column name in your `@JoinColumn` annotation.  Also you were missing braces around the inverseJoinColumns

```
    @JoinTable(name = "users_clients",
      joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")},
          inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName="client_id")})
```

Comment: I have do it straight like you showed, but it still maps with names userS_id and roleS_id. Maybe that some kind of black magic?